# Removing comma from last element in forEach loop PHP

Tags: php, foreach, schema

I am trying to create a dynamic schema markup which should list all of my sitenavigations elements in a schema markup:

My end result should look like this example:

```
    <script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@graph": 
    [
      {
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "@type":"SiteNavigationElement",
          "@id":"#table-of-contents",
          "name": "Section 1",
          "url": "https://www.example.com/page#toc-1"
      },
      {
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "@type":"SiteNavigationElement",
          "@id":"#table-of-contents",
          "name": "Section 2",
          "url": "https://www.example.com/page#toc-2"
      },
      {
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "@type":"SiteNavigationElement",
          "@id":"#table-of-contents",
          "name": "Section 3",
          "url": "https://www.example.com/page#toc-3"
      },
      {
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "@type":"SiteNavigationElement",
          "@id":"#pagination",
          "name": "Previous page",
          "url": "https://www.example.com/page1"
      },
      {
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "@type":"SiteNavigationElement",
          "@id":"#pagination",
          "name": "Next page",
          "url": "https://www.example.com/page2"
      } // Last item doesn't have a comma
    ]
}
</script>
```

I have created a code that does create the schema successfully.

The only problem I got: How can I remove the , from the last item in my forEach loop?

Been searching around for a solution. Probally should use a counter or something similar?

My code:

```
$string  = '<script type="application/ld+json" id="hejhest">
                {
                    "@context":"https://schema.org",
                    "@graph":
                    [';
foreach ( $primaryNav as $navItem ) {
        $string .= '{';
        $string .= '"@contex":"https://schema.org/",';
        $string .= '"@type": "SiteNavigationElement",';
$string .= '"@id": "#table-of-contents",';
$string .= '"name": "'. $navItem->title. '",';
        $string .= '"url":"' . $navItem->url . '"';
        $string .= '}';
        if (// some if-statement about not being last in forEach loop) {
            $string .= ',';
        }

    }
    $string .= ']
            }
            </script>';
    echo $string;
```

Comment: Manually building JSON is just asking for trouble. Put your data into an array and encode the whole thing. Let PHP worry about where a comma should go and where it shouldn't.

Comment: rtrim($string, ',');